# Searching File in a directory recursively using Pre-Order Post Order and InOrder

Tags: java, tree

When I write a code to search file in a directory recursively, for example I apply the method below:

```
public void list(File file) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    for (File child : children) {
        list(child);
    }
}
```

If I need to show it in pre-order, in-order and post-order traversal, How can I do it?

I am not able to related tree traversal with this file search.

Comment: This is not much to do with file search.  Do you know how to do pre/post-order traversal in general?

Comment: Also, in-order traversal only really makes sense for binary trees.

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) explain it well enough?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know these three traversals but I want to co-relate them with this file search context

Comment: @Cam: If you know the basic idea of how to write pre/post-order tree traversals, then I don't see why there's a problem applying it to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in pre-order, because the parent is processed (printed) before the children. If you moved the print to after the loop, it would be post-order. In-order would not make too much sense in this case. If you had a binary tree, it would be if you processed the parent in-between processing each child.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, Is In-Order traversal possible in this case?

Comment: "Possible" yes. You could process the parent after processing the first child, for example. It would not make sense, though.

Comment: If you had a binary tree where the left sub-tree were items lower than the parent, and the right sub-tree items greater than the parent, then in-order processing would print the tree in order. That is an example of when you would use it. But here it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is pre-order traversal.

This is post-order traversal:

```
public void list(File file) { 
    if(file == null)return;  
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    for (File child : children) {
        list(child);
    }
   System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

And in-order traversal does not have a natural definition for a general tree